# Firebase query startAt always returning at least one item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a bit confused on the behaviour of the firebase `startAt()` query. 
I am trying to filter all items inserted after my routine runs. In order to do so I persisted the system time in a `createdAt` field. 
What I want to achieve is to have all items created after the present system time. 
Matter of fact, the last record of my dataset is always returned even if created in the past.
Here is a snippet:

```
let now = getServerTime(Firebase.database().ref('/'))();

listener_added = Firebase.database().ref(url)
    .orderByChild('createdAt').startAt(now)
    .on('child_added', snapshot => {....
```

It should return nothing as soon as I don't add any new row to the table. 
It returns wrongly the last row in the dataset with a createdAt timestamp lower than the "now" variable. Matter of fact only the last (in time) row is returned, all other rows are skipped.

Here is a json snippet:

```
   {
  "-LffdRyzER4ZH9HGJYcs" : {
    "autore" : "Mauro Minenna",
    "changedAt" : 1558676888318,
    "changedBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "cliente" : "-Layy4mzKi1RzW3P_-2A",
    "createdAt" : 1558676876634,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556964000000,
    "ean" : "2000000000046",
    "editore" : "Cologno",
    "history" : {
      "-LfcNPniyo0kyzO4qOtP" : {
        "at" : 1558676876634,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-LfcNSeKMRRaiokup_YF" : {
        "at" : 1558676888318,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "O"
      },
      "-LffacR-OYIrM3brQHsy" : {
        "at" : 1558730934167,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/01/-LVwVrAzOPZGTvhrpSiN",
        "source" : "clone",
        "stato" : "O"
      },
      "-LffdRyypntuZuqiNlPb" : {
        "at" : 1558731673702,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "clone",
        "stato" : "O"
      },
      "-Lfjvcez3vouQYlWQHUM" : {
        "at" : 1558803549013,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "bolla",
        "stato" : "R"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "ordine" : "-Ldzmvb8TSu8cGFwRJVl",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "11.00",
    "prezzoTotale" : "11.00",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "11.00",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "R",
    "titolo" : "Una prova"
  },
  "-Lfjqw-ukiL6NYRO3sug" : {
    "autore" : "Alessandro Manzoni",
    "categoria" : "-LL59jknmY4v2PEDvPn3",
    "cliente" : "-Lb2sFXsqfKciliy0F0f",
    "createdAt" : 1558802317515,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556791200000,
    "ean" : "2000000000015",
    "editore" : "Einaudi",
    "history" : {
      "-Lfjqd7_DbQ1ypU0mJkW" : {
        "at" : 1558802317515,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-Lfjqw-rRJkOoP7C-CGh" : {
        "at" : 1558802317515,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-LfjwW1C05Dj0FAsAcV0" : {
        "at" : 1558803779872,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "bolla",
        "stato" : "R"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brucabook.appspot.com/o/images%2Fbooks%2F-L0Lp-qQXGuhOi9ioFQU%2F-L0TzOM2HoQXDNA8_9sA%2F2000000000015.jpg?alt=media&token=3787cd81-0910-44c9-968b-5f693bc9d219",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "iva" : "a0",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "nomeCategoria" : "Saggi",
    "ordine" : "-LduC3Hov8v3XN5Dm6I9",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "12.90",
    "prezzoTotale" : "12.90",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "12.90",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "R",
    "titolo" : "I Promessi Sposi"
  },
  "-LfjzTsSbfiaTxs_Hkiy" : {
    "autore" : "Matilde Minenna",
    "cliente" : "-Layy4mzKi1RzW3P_-2A",
    "createdAt" : 1558804557497,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556964000000,
    "ean" : "2000000000039",
    "editore" : "Cagnotto",
    "history" : {
      "-LfjzTsRg0TYFdLlI8SB" : {
        "at" : 1558804557497,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-LfjzYuNWMxidgK1WnFr" : {
        "at" : 1558804578109,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "bolla",
        "stato" : "R"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "ordine" : "-Ldzmvb8TSu8cGFwRJVl",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "17.50",
    "prezzoTotale" : "17.50",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "17.50",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "R",
    "titolo" : "La fuga del cavallo morto"
  },
  "-LfjzYuNWMxidgK1WnFq" : {
    "autore" : "Matilde Minenna",
    "cliente" : "-Layy4mzKi1RzW3P_-2A",
    "createdAt" : 1558804557497,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556964000000,
    "ean" : "2000000000039",
    "editore" : "Cagnotto",
    "history" : {
      "-LfjzTsRg0TYFdLlI8SB" : {
        "at" : 1558804557497,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-LfjzYuNWMxidgK1WnFp" : {
        "at" : 1558804578109,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "clone",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-Lfk7pZ2VbvVEq68J2EL" : {
        "at" : 1558807009115,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "bolla",
        "stato" : "R"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "ordine" : "-Ldzmvb8TSu8cGFwRJVl",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "17.50",
    "prezzoTotale" : "17.50",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "17.50",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "R",
    "titolo" : "La fuga del cavallo morto"
  },
  "-Lfk3vXzlHXwV4MXrnRY" : {
    "autore" : "Collodi",
    "categoria" : "-LL59iB3onWyGUb2JCZD",
    "cliente" : "-Layy4mzKi1RzW3P_-2A",
    "createdAt" : 1558805985616,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556964000000,
    "ean" : "2000000000022",
    "editore" : "Mondadori ",
    "history" : {
      "-Lfk3vXxn6_OwIabaUkQ" : {
        "at" : 1558805985616,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brucabook.appspot.com/o/images%2Fbooks%2F-L0Lp-qQXGuhOi9ioFQU%2F-L0TzOM2HoQXDNA8_9sA%2F2000000000022.jpg?alt=media&token=5f5a91a6-4a14-44c0-b7d7-d996936ce72e",
    "imgFullName" : "images/books/-L0Lp-qQXGuhOi9ioFQU/-L0TzOM2HoQXDNA8_9sA/2000000000022.jpg",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "iva" : "a0",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "nomeCategoria" : "Gialli",
    "ordine" : "-Ldzmvb8TSu8cGFwRJVl",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "13.50",
    "prezzoTotale" : "13.50",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "13.50",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "D",
    "titolo" : "Pinocchio"
  },
  "-Lfk7pZ2VbvVEq68J2EK" : {
    "autore" : "Matilde Minenna",
    "cliente" : "-Layy4mzKi1RzW3P_-2A",
    "createdAt" : 1558804557497,
    "createdBy" : "AGdyklHWhjfNk7wYYh1tPmxss573",
    "dataOrdine" : 1556964000000,
    "ean" : "2000000000039",
    "editore" : "Cagnotto",
    "history" : {
      "-LfjzTsRg0TYFdLlI8SB" : {
        "at" : 1558804557497,
        "source" : "user",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-LfjzYuNWMxidgK1WnFp" : {
        "at" : 1558804578109,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "clone",
        "stato" : "D"
      },
      "-Lfk7pZ2VbvVEq68J2EJ" : {
        "at" : 1558807009115,
        "path" : "bolla/2019/05/-Lffcnwdy7U6HSnPYzLR",
        "source" : "clone",
        "stato" : "D"
      }
    },
    "imgFirebaseUrl" : "",
    "imgUrl" : "",
    "manSconto" : false,
    "ordine" : "-Ldzmvb8TSu8cGFwRJVl",
    "pezzi" : 1,
    "prezzoListino" : "17.50",
    "prezzoTotale" : "17.50",
    "prezzoUnitario" : "17.50",
    "sconto" : 0,
    "stato" : "D",
    "titolo" : "La fuga del cavallo morto"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON that you're reading (as text, **no** screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did it. Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: What are the values of `url` and `now`? Essentially what we need is a snippet of code with no external dependencies that we can run to reproduce the problem against the JSON you've now shared. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to make it clear how to do this, and why this is so incredibly useful when asking for help on why your code doesn't work. A simple way to force yourself to have such an MCVE, is to reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin.com.